# angularjs static searchbox in all pages

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-routing

I have a searchbox , list of items , when I click on each item it will take me to the item info tempate.
right now in my below code the searchbox is inside the items.html and it only appears in there meaning it does not appear when i am on the intem.html template viewing the info .
Can you assist me in keeping my searchbox view-able in all pages and outside the `ng-view`? and yet the items list will not appear when I am viewing an item info but the searchbox appears . but when I search , the `ng-view` will show the search results in this `ng-view` instead of the item info ?

This is the current code :

```js
items.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/items', {
      templateUrl: 'items.html',
      controller: 'ItemsController',
       //some API code happens here to get the search results list 
      }
    })
    .when('/items/:id', {
      templateUrl: 'item.html',
      controller: 'ItemController',
          //some API code happens here to get the info 
       
        }
      }
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/items'
    });
```

```html
 <div class="container">

  <hr>

    <div ng-view></div>
  </div>


<!--items.html-->

  <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search ..." ng-model="search" >
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="item in items | filter:search">
      <td><a ng-href="#/items/{{item.id}}" ></a>
      <td> {{ item.title }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>


<!-- item.html>
```

Comment: you dont need a comma here `controller: 'ItemsController',`

Comment: @Hareesh that won't make any difference